# What is a word for the act of preparing a home for first/new occupancy?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

Not necessarily the absolute form - as in a brand new house - but just the act of doing any final prep work in anticipation of a new occupant for a home. 'Housewarming' comes to mind, but that seems to be something that occurs post-occupancy.

Comment: A punch list is a list of the final details that have to be attended to before construction or renovation is complete.  A housewarming is a celebration held after occupancy has taken place, in which guests bring the occupants gifts for the house.

Answer (score 1):

***Prepare*** appears to be the term commonly used:

- How to [prepare](http://www.allbusiness.com/how-to-prepare-your-rental-property-for-occupancy-4086-1.html) Your Rental Property for Occupancy. (www.allbusiness.com)
- [Prepare](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/mortgages-real-estate/10/renting-out-home.asp) for the new tenant. (www.investopedia.com)
- 8 Tips to [Prepare](http://www.realtor.com/advice/8-tips-prepare-a-home-for-rental/) a Home for Rental. (www.realtor.com)

Comment: There is a term for the related task of preparing a new home (specifically a _model home_) or even a high-end resale or rental home, for _showing_ to prospective buyers or lessees, which can include placing window treatments, furniture, objets d'art, etc. This process is called **staging**.

Answer (score 0):

For a not-new home, if the preparation involves anything more than cleaning and painting (for example, new curtains or carpets) it is called **refurbishing** or (rarely) **refurbishment. Renovation** is mentioned as a synonym.

(Free Dictionary)

re·fur·bish  (rē-fûr′bĭsh)
tr.v. re·fur·bished, re·fur·bish·ing, re·fur·bish·es
To make clean, bright, or fresh again; renovate.

re·fur′bish·ment n.